# Use smart things SDK for our own custom android app and provision Samsung smart devices, ex- fridge etc (not using Samsung smart things app)

Tags: android, iot, samsung, smartthings, smart-app-banner

I want to create a section in my existing Android app to make my end-users capable of connecting & discover their Samsung brand smart devices and appliances using **Smart Things SDK**

I have explored the [API](https://developer.smartthings.com/docs/api/public/) 3 documented on the Samsung website but did not get the idea for scanning and provisioning(connecting) Samsung devices via Custom Android App and do not want to use the **SmartThings** app which is there in the play store for scanning and provisioning Samsung Devices.

Any help or suggestions will be very helpful to me.
Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Please help @Stackoverflow team

Comment: I am also facing the same issue, need to scan & discover Samsung smart appliances from my custom app.